Was the Terminator the first robot of that nature in science fiction?
Note: The eyes of the Terminator I think were real but he did not rely on them, although interestingly they would have blocked his electronic  eyes, so I wonder how that worked.
A robot disguised as a human is not what I meant - I mean, something that is flesh and machine, but started out purely as machine, not as a human. The robots of The Second Variety were mechanical but they also may have employed real body parts and if so, it could be argued that they preceded the idea in the Terminator except Terminators used flesh purely as camouflage. The RUR creatures are not relevant here since they are not a combination of machine and flesh but rather artificially grown flesh IIRC.
"Cyborg" to me always meant an artificially enhanced organism, but importantly, originally a naturally-born organism.
I am not sure Arnold's Terminator was a cyborg. He was a robot with real flesh added, but the skin and eyes I guess were not essential and he was, it goes without saying, never human. (In later flicks, we saw it seems to me that Skynet started out by modifying humans into cyborgs.)
So my question is, was Cameron (or whoever thought of the idea) the first to come up with a robot "enhanced" with real human tissue (although presumably the tissue was cultured, not taken from humans)?

The eyes were robotic and the flesh was purely cosmetic, and only served as a disguise.  The skin is definitely not required, as shown by the skeletal terminators hunting humans in the first scenes.  (And by the skeletalized terminator still fighting after having its flesh burned off.)  The earliest "robot disguised as human for infiltration purposes" I can think of is Dick's "Second Variety."

There are at least two distinct questions here: "Was the Terminator the first robot of that nature in science fiction" and "is there a different term than "cyborg" for such a robot?" The former is a [history-of] question while the latter is a [terminology] question, and the answer to one does not necessarily provide the answer to the other. As such, I think they should be asked separately rather than being packaged together as a two-for-the-price-of-one deal.

If I remember right, the first "robots" (R. U. R., Karel Čapek, 1920) were made entirely of artificial flesh and blood, and could pass for human beings. But I don't think that's what you want.

@user14111 R.U.R. robots being more like Blade Runner replicants than TNG's Data no doubt you realize.

@LogicDictates: You are right but I am pretty sure there is no term specifically for a robot that only uses flesh to fool humans and, of course, to time travel. "Cyborg" is probably the closest even if wrong technically. The more important question is whether this was an original idea of Cameron and I think it was: It also provided some very good details, i.e. (pun intended) the self-surgery scene and the idea that the Terminator seemed to deteriorate over time, perhaps due to wounds. This had no real effect beyond its progressive difficulty blending in.

Jonas in Book of the New Sun was a damaged machine patched with human flesh.

The Lem short story "The Mask" from 1976 has a killer robot so thoroughly disguised as a human woman that the robot itself is not aware of its true nature for much of the story. Not sure if this would count, since the nature of the "flesh" is not quite clear (it is mentioned that it doesn't bleed when cut, so might not be tissue after all). Not an answer, but still worth mentioning as early example of a terminator robot.

Metropolis. (Novel by Thea von Harbou 1925, Fritz Lang's motion picture 1927, IMDB.)
Everyone is familiar with the poster of a shiny robot female (Technically the false Maria, played by Brigitte Helm) being created inside a machine. That's from the most popular movie poster:

Illustration by Heinz Schulz-Neudamm. Copyright expired.
Another, lesser known poster-version of the character (false) Maria of the Maschinenmensch (a worker class of humanoid robots) shows her with the outer layer added:

Artist unknown. Out of copyright.
Images are not subject to copyright, but belong to Paramount studios.

Very nice. I think this is the right answer.

Are you sure the poster shows the Maschinenmensch? Because that really looks like the contraption Maria is lying in during the transformation: https://youtu.be/VJVUQ5gHsZI?t=120. The fake Maria is sitting in a chair without the same kind of machinery in the background.

@EikePierstorff You might have a point there, I'll try to make time to watch it again and check then update the answer.

Philip K. Dick had The Second Variety (a story I found absolutely creepy) was published in 1953.
Pohl and Kornbluth's Wolfsbane from 1959 I still think one of their best, and Fred Saberhagen started writing the Berserker stories in 1963 (and at least one of them I've always thought the ancestor of The Terminator movie).
But I see The Second Variety as the start, and I've never forgotten this:
The claws weren’t like other weapons. They were alive, from any practical standpoint, whether the Governments wanted to admit it or not. They were not machines. They were living
things, spinning, creeping, shaking themselves up suddenly from the gray ash and darting toward a man, climbing up him, rushing for his throat. And that was what they had been designed to do. Their job.
"They did their job well. Especially lately, with the new designs coming up. Now they repaired themselves. They were on their own ... Down below the surface automatic machinery stamped them out. Human beings stayed a long way off. It was too risky; nobody wanted to be around them. They were left to themselves. And they seemed to be doing all right. The new designs were faster, more complex. More efficient."

Since you are asking Science Fiction in general and not movies specifically, the German Perry Rhodan pulp series featured (first in issue 403 from 1969) the "Vario 500" robot, an egg shaped device that was constructed to disguise itself with a variety of human looking "cocoon masks" made from cultured flesh. The purpose was essentially infiltration (in early issues the robot impersonated a politician influencing a somewhat isolationist goverment to join an alliance) so a bit similar, if rather more benign than the Terminator.

There are also the androids of I, Mudd, the Star Trek TOS Season 2 episode that aired November 3, 1967.  In an early scene a male android announces to the bridge that he is in control of the Enterprise and opens a cover in his abdomen revealing he has an electronic and mechanical interior under his human-looking skin, hair, fingernails, etc.
The story summaries I've found don't say whether the androids' skin/hair are organic or inorganic.

Androids resembling humans is the very nature of androids; but making "fake cyborg" with real flesh is what I think Cameron may have invented.
